# Slowing down animation to see twisted Dinis

Tags: animation

Please help to visualize the given (isometrically twisted Dini) surface with unmoving grid on Box so slowly that at each step the Parametric lines can be seen on the surface. Also the grid position of maximum radius ( corresponding to Twst=0 ) location should not change during animation.

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot3D[ Cos[Twst] {Sin[ph] Cos[v], -(Cos[ph]+ Log[Tan[ph/2]]), Sin[ph] Sin[v]} + Sin[Twst] {0, v, 0}, {ph, .15,
2.4},{v, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLabel -> " TwistingPseudoSphere", PlotPoints -> 80,BoxRatios -> {1, 2.5, 1}], {{Twst, 0.3}, -0.3, 0.3}]
```

[image: Continuously Twisted Dini]

Comment: `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"`

Comment: `PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}`？

Comment: `Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Cos[Twst] {Sin[ph] Cos[v], -(Cos[ph] + Log[Tan[ph/2]]), 
     Sin[ph] Sin[v]} + Sin[Twst] {0, v, 0}, {ph, .15, 2.4}, {v, 0, 
   2 Pi}, PlotLabel -> " TwistingPseudoSphere", PlotPoints -> 80, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 2.5, 1}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {{Twst, 0}, -0.3, 0.3}]`   ?